# CQRS how to display failed commands in the GUI

Tags: error-handling, cqrs, ui, event-handling

I am trying to use CQRS in my project and I was thinking how the GUI gets notified about failures in the GUI, when commands are fire and forget. My commandhandlers are not returning anything, but emitting domain events, that capture the result of the command.

Lets say in the classical example of an ecommerce app. If I want to add something to the shopping cart, but it could not be added due to some policy or whatever, how is the UI notified and can show something like "Could not add item  because .

The only solution I can think of is to subscribe from the UI to the events and publish them through RabbitMQ or similar. Also I am not sure, how that exact browser gets the result of that event, and what exactly he should subscribe to. I would need to specifically subscribe to only get that certain event and not anyones event.

Comment: I'd advise you to keep your mind open to the possibility that "fire and forget commands" are actually a bad idea.

Comment: Why are your commands "fire and forget", if you want to give the user feedback on the result of the command?

Comment: This is what I learned about cqrs, that you dispatch a command and dont wait for a for a result (synchronous way) but let the events flow through the system that can again dispatch more commands etc.

Answer (score 1):

> Lets say in the classical example of an ecommerce app. If I want to add something to the shopping cart, but it could not be added due to some policy or whatever, how is the UI notified and can show something like "Could not add item because

How would the UI be notified in the *success* case?

It's exactly the same except instead of "item added to cart" it's "cart error added to cart".

Comment: This. Most GUIs today are event driven and need to subscribe to all kinds of domain events, either. A change in the domain state (like a change of the shopping cart's state) should fire an "cart state changed" event, and the UI can subscribe to that event. For making errors visible, the cart should have a "latest error" field which the UI can query after getting notified,

Answer (score 0):

Have the command handler return the event that the command has emitted (in addition to emitting it to the event bus). This event will, by definition, carry all the necessary information.

Comment: this would also be an option. I just learned that commands should never return anything in cqrs, I think I followed that suggestion too blindly. Many of the examples online use commandgateways where the handler is not returning anything, so it can run concurrently to the request.